# Determine the constant so that the integral is minizimed

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

Presume that $a<b$ and that $f$ is continuous in the interval $[a,b]$,

Determine K so that the integral:

$$\int_a^b (f(x) - K)^2 dx$$

is minimized, also what is this minimum?

I found similar questions but none were working with $f(x).$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
\int_a^b (f(x) - K)^2 dx=K^2\int_a^bdx-2K\int_a^b f(x)\: dx+\int_a^b [f(x)]^2 dx
$$ and one may see the above expression as a **quadratic function** depending on $K$.

Comment: Fanstastic hint.  I love this.  Once I solved it, the final answer made so much sense I was upset that I didn't see it immediately.

Comment: @Olivier Oloa hmm so I wrote it as $(k-1)^2 \int_a^b f(x) + f(x)^2 dx$ and $(k-1)^2=0$ if $k=1$ so the minimum would be $1 - 2\int_a^b f(x) dx + \int_a^b f(x)^2 dx $ 
or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: @JohnDoe You may rather write $\displaystyle \int_a^b (f(x) - K)^2 dx$ as $$\left[(b-a)\left(K-\color{red}{\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx} \right)^2+\int_a^b[f(x)]^2dx-\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\int_a^b f(x)dx \right)^2\right]$$ then observe that it is minimum when the first square vanishes that is when $\displaystyle K=\color{red}{\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx}$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa how did you get to that expression? By completing the square and rewriting it? How do you know that's when it is minimum?

Comment: @JohnDoe You always have $\displaystyle (b-a)\left(K-\color{red}{\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx} \right)^2\ge0$, so for what value of $K$ is it minimum?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Oh right I thought $(b-a)$ could be negative which it cant be. How did you go about writing that expression, I can't seem to get to the same one.

Comment: One may obtain it by completing the square, observing that $\int_a^bdx=b-a>$, one gets $\displaystyle =K^2\int_a^bdx-2K\int_a^b f(x)\: dx=\left[(b-a)\left(K-\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx \right)^2-\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\int_a^b f(x)dx \right)^2\right].$

Answer (score 3):

Let the function $g(x,y)=(f(x)-y)^2$. Set 
$
G(y)=\int_{a}^{b}g(x,y)\;{\rm d}x.
$
The min point of $G$ is a critical point of $G$. That is, a point $y^\ast$ such that 
$
G^\prime(y)=0
$.
By [Libinitz integral rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html), 
$$
G^\prime (y)\Big|_{y=y^\ast}
=
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d } y}\int_{a}^{b}g(x,y)\;{\rm d } x\Big|_{y=y^\ast}
=
\int_{a}^{b}\frac{{\rm \partial}}{{\rm \partial } y}g(x,y)\;{\rm d } x\Big|_{y=y^\ast}
=
\int_{a}^{b}-(f(x)-y)\;{\rm d } x\Big|_{y=y^\ast}
\\
=
(b-a)y\Big|_{y=y^\ast}-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\;{\rm d} x=0
$$
Then the minimum point of $G(y)$ is 
$$
y^\ast=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x){\rm d} x
$$
And 
$$
G\left(y^\ast\right)=G\left(\frac{1}{b-a)}\int_{a}^{b}f(x){\rm d}x \right)
\\
=\int_{a}^{b}
\left[
f(x)- \frac{1}{(b-a)}\int_{a}^{b}f(x){\rm d}x 
\right]^2
{\rm d}x
\\
= \int_a^b f(x)^2{\rm d} x-\frac{1}{(b-a)}\left[ \int_a^b f(x){\rm d} x\right]^2
$$

Answer (score 2):

It may be overkill for this question (the other answers relied very efficiently on calculus), but I think the $L^2$ approach must be at least spoken about here.

Let us consider the Hilbert space $L^2(a,b)$ of (classes of) functions whose square is integrable on $[a,b]$, with its usual inner product $(f|g) = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \mathrm{d}x$ and the norm $||f|| = \sqrt{(f|f)}$.

Then  $\int_a^b (f(x) - K)^2 \mathrm{d}x = (f-K|f-K)$ is the distance of the function $f$ to the constant function $K$. By the projection on convex theorem, more precisely on a closed subspace here (the constant functions are a closed subspace non empty set of $L^2(a,b)$), the minimum is attained at the only constant function $C$ such that $(f - C|K) = 0$ for all constants $K$.

You can then easily check (by evaluating at $K = 1$ for example) that $C = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x.$

As I said, it may be overkill here, but the result presented here will easily generalize to similar problems where calculus will not be able to provide an answer (and is often deemed as the classical way to handle this kind of problem).

PS : Plus, I feel it gives a nice geometric interpretation of the result : the closest constant to $f$ in terms of $L^2$ norm is its own integral ; one could interpret it as a sort of "mean" of the function $f$ on the interval.